# How to modify Johnson's elementary cycles algorithm to cap maximum cycle length?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm, networkx

I would like to modify the [networkx implementation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/_modules/networkx/algorithms/cycles.html#simple_cycles) of Johnson's algorithm for finding *all* elementary cycles in a graph (also copied below) so that is does not search for cycles larger than some maximum length.

```
def simple_cycles(G):
    def _unblock(thisnode,blocked,B):
        stack=set([thisnode])
        while stack:
            node=stack.pop()
            if node in blocked:
                blocked.remove(node)
                stack.update(B[node])
                B[node].clear()

    # Johnson's algorithm requires some ordering of the nodes.
    # We assign the arbitrary ordering given by the strongly connected comps
    # There is no need to track the ordering as each node removed as processed.
    subG = type(G)(G.edges_iter()) # save the actual graph so we can mutate it here
                              # We only take the edges because we do not want to
                              # copy edge and node attributes here.
    sccs = list(nx.strongly_connected_components(subG))
    while sccs:
        scc=sccs.pop()
        # order of scc determines ordering of nodes
        startnode = scc.pop()
        # Processing node runs "circuit" routine from recursive version
        path=[startnode]
        blocked = set() # vertex: blocked from search?
        closed = set() # nodes involved in a cycle
        blocked.add(startnode)
        B=defaultdict(set) # graph portions that yield no elementary circuit
        stack=[ (startnode,list(subG[startnode])) ]  # subG gives component nbrs
        while stack:
            thisnode,nbrs = stack[-1]
            if nbrs:
                nextnode = nbrs.pop()
#                    print thisnode,nbrs,":",nextnode,blocked,B,path,stack,startnode
#                    f=raw_input("pause")

                if nextnode == startnode:
                    yield path[:]
                    closed.update(path)
#                        print "Found a cycle",path,closed
                elif nextnode not in blocked:
                    path.append(nextnode)
                    stack.append( (nextnode,list(subG[nextnode])) )
                    closed.discard(nextnode)
                    blocked.add(nextnode)
                    continue
            # done with nextnode... look for more neighbors
            if not nbrs:  # no more nbrs
                if thisnode in closed:
                    _unblock(thisnode,blocked,B)
                else:
                    for nbr in subG[thisnode]:
                        if thisnode not in B[nbr]:
                            B[nbr].add(thisnode)
                stack.pop()
                assert path[-1]==thisnode
                path.pop()

        # done processing this node
        subG.remove_node(startnode)
        H=subG.subgraph(scc)  # make smaller to avoid work in SCC routine
        sccs.extend(list(nx.strongly_connected_components(H)))
```

Of course, I'd also accept a suggestion that differs from the implementation above but runs in similar time. Also, my project uses networkx, so feel free to use any other function from that library, such as `shortest_path`.

(Note: not homework!)

### Edit

Dorijan Cirkveni suggested (if I understood correctly):

```
        if len(blocked) >= limit + 1:
            continue

        elif nextnode == startnode:
            yield path[:]
```

However, that doesn't work. Here's a counterexample:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(2, 3)
G.add_edge(3, 1)
G.add_edge(3, 2)
G.add_edge(3, 4)

my_cycles = list(simple_cycles(G, limit = 3)) # Modification
nx_cycles = list(nx.simple_cycles(G)) # Original networkx code
print("MY:", my_cycles)
print("NX:", nx_cycles)
```

Will output

```
MY: [[2, 3]]
NX: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Also, if we substitute `blocked` by `stack` or `path`, the result will be correct for this example, but will give the wrong answer for other graphs.

Comment: It looks to me like it's as simple as changing `if nbrs` to `if nbrs and len(path)<limit`  And change `if not nbrs` to `else`.  I think that does it, but I don't have time to test it right now.  [if anyone else wants to write up a full answer based on this, please feel free - just make sure that it's more than just the bare minimum answer].

Comment: @Joel, unfortunately that still leads to the same answer as Dorijan Cirkveni's answer.

Comment: The current version of the library `NetworkX` now has this feature in the function `simple_cycles` as an optional argument (`length_bound`).
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles
It is based on this article:
Finding All Bounded-Length Simple Cycles in a Directed Graph A. Gupta and T. Suzumura https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.10094

Answer (score 2):

This is a highly modified version of this code, but at least it is working.

```
def simple_cycles(G, limit):
    subG = type(G)(G.edges())
    sccs = list(nx.strongly_connected_components(subG))
    while sccs:
        scc = sccs.pop()
        startnode = scc.pop()
        path = [startnode]
        blocked = set()
        blocked.add(startnode)
        stack = [(startnode, list(subG[startnode]))]

        while stack:
            thisnode, nbrs = stack[-1]

            if nbrs and len(path) < limit:
                nextnode = nbrs.pop()
                if nextnode == startnode:
                    yield path[:]
                elif nextnode not in blocked:
                    path.append(nextnode)
                    stack.append((nextnode, list(subG[nextnode])))
                    blocked.add(nextnode)
                    continue
            if not nbrs or len(path) >= limit:
                blocked.remove(thisnode)
                stack.pop()
                path.pop()
        subG.remove_node(startnode)
        H = subG.subgraph(scc)
        sccs.extend(list(nx.strongly_connected_components(H)))
```

Comment: For much better performance I would recommend using this library: graph-tool.skewed.de

Comment: By any chance do you have a similar version of your code using graph-tool at hand?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I haven't. @Hebo

Answer (score -1):

You only need to change two things:

1. The definition line (obviously)

   `def simple_cycles(G,limit):`
2. Add an overriding condition somewhere in the next node processor (example below:)

   ```
           ...
           if blocked.size>=limit+1:
               pass
           elif if nextnode == startnode:
               yield path[:] ...
   ```

   Bonus: Using `==` instead of `>=` will result in the function running as there is no limit when a negative value is used, as opposed to not returning any nodes.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what you mean in the "bonus" comment.  Could you reword it?

Comment: That was my first reaction as well, but it does not work. I'll update my question with more details. Thank you!